# Image alignment issue in PDF using iText pdfHTML

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I am trying to export HTML page into a PDF using iText7.1.0 and pdfHTML2.0.0. For some reason, the pages have formatting issue for the Pie chart images (aligned horizontally in HTML whereas vertically aligned in PDF) and the table (titled "Features") on left is pushed down vertically. The [jsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/Sparks245/svqvp724/) to my HTML code that is being used by PDF renderer.

Below is the Java code used for rendering the PDF (Page1.html is the same HTML code in the fiddle):

```
/*
 * Copyright 2016-2017, iText Group NV.
 * This example was created by Bruno Lowagie.
 * It was written in the context of the following book:
 * https://leanpub.com/itext7_pdfHTML
 * Go to http://developers.itextpdf.com for more info.
 */
package com.itextpdf.htmlsamples.chapter01;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter;
import com.itextpdf.licensekey.LicenseKey;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


/**
 * Converts a simple HTML file to PDF using File objects
 * as arguments for the convertToPdf() method.
 */
public class C01E03_HelloWorld {

    /** The Base URI of the HTML page. */
    public static final String BASEURI = "src/main/resources/html/";
    /** The path to the source HTML file. */
    public static final String SRC = String.format("%sPage1.html", BASEURI);
    /** The target folder for the result. */
    public static final String TARGET = "target/results/ch01/";
    /** The path to the resulting PDF file. */
    public static final String DEST = String.format("%stest-03.pdf", TARGET);

    /**
     * The main method of this example.
     *
     * @param args no arguments are needed to run this example.
     * @throws IOException Signals that an I/O exception has occurred.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        LicenseKey.loadLicenseFile("C://Users//Sparks//Desktop//itextkey-0.xml");
        File file = new File(TARGET);
        file.mkdirs();
        new C01E03_HelloWorld().createPdf(BASEURI, SRC, DEST);
    }

    /**
     * Creates the PDF file.
     *
     * @param baseUri the base URI
     * @param src the path to the source HTML file
     * @param dest the path to the resulting PDF
     * @throws IOException Signals that an I/O exception has occurred.
     */
    public void createPdf(String baseUri, String src, String dest) throws IOException {
        HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new File(src), new File(dest));
    }
}
```

The output PDF file is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_r9u9ln7pC0QZGNPglpFIdlnWd19FxQa/view?usp=sharing). It should have formatting similar to the one in HTML page.

Any suggestions would be helpful.